# How to create multiple input in a angular form and save it to a array

Tags: angular

Based on the number of people selected, I want to give the ability to the users to enter all the names of the users based on the number selected as ave it to an array as name = ["people1", "people2"];

```
<form  [formGroup]="guestList" novalidate>
        <mat-tab-group dynamicHeight #matgroup>

          <mat-tab label="Guest Information">

            <label>Select the number of peope</label>
            <div class="form-group">
              <mat-select name="no" formControlName="no" class="form-control">
                  <mat-option name="no" *ngFor="let number of [1,2,3,4]" [value]="number" >{{number}}</mat-option>
              </mat-select>
            </div>



            <label> People Names</label>
            // **create number of input's depending upon number selected instead of using the array**
            <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let input of [1,2,3,4]">
                  <input type="text" formControlName="Name" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="input.value">

            </div>


          </mat-tab>
         </mat-tab-group>
</form>
```

Comment: You'll want to take a look at FormArrays: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#use-formarray-to-present-an-array-of-formgroups

Comment: Thanks! FormArrays served the purpose.

Comment: You're welcome. Always glad to help.